# Size of plots Knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, word-cloud

I'm trying to change the size of a `wordcloud` but I don't know how to do this. Apparently lower values of `fig.width` make the plot bigger, not smaller, and vice versa. It seems to take up an enormous amount of space, compared to the second plot which is just the right size.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE,fig.width=3>>=
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(1)
freq<-sample(letters,2000,prob=1:26,rep=T)

wordcloud(names(table(freq)),table(freq),min.freq=60,colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"),scale=c(1,.2))
@

<<echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)

freq<-table(freq)

wf<-as.data.frame(freq)
wf$freq<-ordered(wf$freq,levels=wf$freq[order(wf$Freq)])

ggplot(subset(wf,Freq>60),aes(freq,Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1))
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The arguments `fig.width` & `fig.height` provide [aspect-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) between the two axis: in order to indicate the size of the plot in your knitted / exported document, *you should use both of them*, ever (e.g., by using pandoc when knitting a rmarkdown file to a .docx).

Alternatively, the `fig.asp =` let you adjust the size of the image (e.g., multiply current size by 2 with `fig.asp = 2`). However, this method still provides a `fig.height` and `fig.width` parameters during the export (under the hood).